# Store additional details of logged-in user using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I am looking for the right way to store and display additional details of a logged-in user through out my application using Spring Security.

For example, I want to show *Welcome:Mr.Smith (Administrator, Math Dept)* on top of every page. For this I want to obtain the prefix, last name, designation and dept for the logged in user.

I am using a custom `UserDetails` service to fetch a user from the database. While browsing, I found that `Authentication` has `getDetails()`, which can store additional details related to authentication, can I use that method to store additional details?

If yes can you show a simple example? Can I use `AuthenticationSuccessHanlder` to do this job, or am I looking at the problem in a completely wrong way? Should I not handle this in the spring security layer? where should I take care of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra details should be properties of a custom UserDetails class that your custom UserDetailsService returns from its loadUserByName method.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks GreyBeardedGeek. I got it working by adding additional variables to userDetails. Created a class called CustomUserDetails added variables like Department, company etc. In my custom implementation of UserDetailsService, I returned `new CustomUserDetails(new User(dbUser.getUsername(),dbUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(), true, true, true, true, getAuthorities(dbUser)));`   Got help from : [Spring Security](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-set-up-and.html) and [Spring ACL](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-security-simple-acl-using.html) for acl

Answer (score 5):

Besides the need for a custom authentication-provider (an implementation of `UserDetailsService`), that you already identified, this can be done **customizing the defaults that the framework provides** a little further.

The framework provides a `UserDetails` interface and some implementations of it like a `User` class and other.

## Example

In an application of mine I had the need for a person without necessarily being a user of the application.

My way was to extend the already provided **Spring Security** `User` and make my `UserDetailsService` implementation return it.

```
public class RequestUserDetails 
        extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6411988532329234916L;
    private Integer personId;

    public RequestUserDetails(String username, String password, Integer personId,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public Integer getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }
}
```

+

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService
    implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {
    [...]
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        [...]
        return new RequestUserDetails(
                userCreds.getLogin(), 
                userCreds.getPassword(),
                person.getId(),
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRoles())
        );
    }
}
```

Simplistic **Usages**:

- At a controller level with a `javax.security.Principal` parameter (not tied to Spring MVC):

  ```
  ( (RequestUserDetails) ((Authentication)principal).getPrincipal() ).getPersonId()
  ```
- At a controller level tied to Spring MVC `@Controller` annotation,  with a `Authentication` parameter:

  ```
  ( (RequestUserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal() ).getPersonId()
  ```

If you need further reference on Spring Security `UserDetails` go to [API javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html)